# Python ValueError when putting one array into another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, signal-processing, valueerror

I'm trying to insert one array into another, but I think I'm having a dimensioning issue with the arrays, leading to a ValueError. The exponential segment I'm trying to insert lives in EXP and prints as I'd expect, but running len() on it returns 1. Why would an array that prints with more than one element return a len() of 1? Code snippet below:

```
SPR = 48000  # Hz
duration = 0.2  # second
t = numpy.linspace(0, duration, duration * SPR)    
p_list = [0, numpy.pi, 0]   

SIGNALS = [(16000 * numpy.sin((2 * numpy.pi * t * 20) + p)).astype('int16')
            for p in p_list]
EXP = [(16000 * (2**(-100*t))).astype('int16')]

e=EXP[0:4200]
print(e)
print(len(e))
SIGNALS[0][600:4800] = e
```

returns

```
[array([16000, 15976, 15953, ...,     0,     0,     0], dtype=int16)]
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Experiments/actronika-exp.py", line 87, in <module>
    SIGNALS[0][600:4800] = e
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the brackets in `EXP = [(16000 * (2**(-100*t))).astype('int16')]`?  That makes a list.  Is that intentional?  Since you also do `EXP[0:4200]` I don't think so.  Notice your `e` has len 1, not 4200!

Comment: Yes @hpaulj, turns out I thought I needed the extra brackets to create a list, not realising that operating on `t` would do that anyway. The `len(e) = 1` thing confused me, but makes sense now I realise I was creating a 2D array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are inserting the array inside a list when you do:

```
X = [np.array([0, ...])]
```

Thus X is a list with a array inside, I think you should just do:

```
X = np.array([0, ...])
```

However, if you need the array inside list thing, you should change this line

```
e=EXP[0:4200]
```

to

```
e=EXP[0][0:4200]
```

Now you are taking the first array, inside the list EXP.

Comment: This was exactly my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```py
[array([16000, 15976, 15953, ...,     0,     0,     0], dtype=int16)]
```

This (`e`) is a numpy array inside a python list. `len(e)` returns the list's length, which *is* 1, since it contains 1 element: the numpy array